# How to run get-vm command on windows powershell

Tags: powershell

I tried run get-vm command on windows powershell. It is throwing this exception:

> "Error in script : The term 'Get-VM' is not recognized as the name of
> a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
> is correct and try again."

but I run same command on system center powershell it's run successful. But i need run on windows powershell. can i run it on windows powershell?

Comment: Are you running ps 2.0 trying to remote control a hyper-v server? If so you need to download the RSAT tools if I remember correctly and activate the "hyper-v powershell module" windows feature

Answer (score 2):

Import the VMM snapin. System Center's Powershell shortcut loads it per default. Vanilla Powershell doesn't.

Use `Get-PSSnapin -Registered` to list all available snap-ins. The one you are looking for is `Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager`

Load the snap-in: `Add-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager`

Get and set default VMM Server: `get-vmmserver myVMMServer`.VMMServer`or use`-VMMServer` switch to specify the VMM server the cmdlet is going to interact with.

Comment: Thanks for answer. i was using "Get-PSSnapin -Registered" powershell was showing 'WDeploySnapin3.0'. i was using "Get-PSSnapin" i was seeing 'Microsoft.Powershell.Core' but i run get-vm command on virtual machine manager powershell console is't not throwing any error

Comment: i find different solution.
First set Execution Policy to RemoteSigned by 'Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned'
and Import Virtual Machine Module by 'Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\psModules\virtualmachinemanager\virtualmachinemanager.psd1" and i run get-vm script successfully. But i call same script by c# this script not working.