# Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager is not installed on this machine

Tags: powershell-2.0

I want to use get-vm command from powershell.

> $my_vm = get-vm -Name MY_VM_NAME

Have error message that

The term 'get-vm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
 script f ile, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
 if a path was incl uded, verify that the path is correct and try
 again.

I found that I need to install Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager
([how to run get-vm command on windows powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435177/how-to-run-get-vm-command-on-windows-powershell))

Execute that:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-PSSnapin -Name
>   Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager

Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMa
chineManager' is not installed on this machine.
At line:1 char:13

Do I really need to install that huge tool? I don't have enough space on my VM. 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10712

Is it another way to solve issue with get-vm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can look in to connecting to the machine that has VMM on it.  You can use remoting to do this.  You can find some more info about it here:  http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/creating-remote-sessions-powershell-20?page=3